# Lazy Load on event OR on scroll

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

Is it possible to have Lazy load fire on either a set event or scroll rather than just one or the other.

I have a paginated list that I want to display images on a page change, but I still want images to display on scrolling as well.

Thanks.